# Rails 3 - What is the correct way to create a resource that has nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, idioms

I'm building a Wedding website that will allow guests to login with an invitation code and RSVP online. My models are as follows:

**Invitation**

```
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible # None are accessible

  # Validation 
  code_regex = /\A[A-Z0-9]{8}\z/

  validates :code, :presence => true, 
                   :length => { :is => 8 },
                   :uniqueness => true,
                   :format => { :with => code_regex }

  validates :guest_count, :presence => true,
                          :inclusion => { :in => 1..2 }

  has_one :rsvp, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

**Rsvp**

```
class Rsvp < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :guests_attributes

  belongs_to :invitation
  has_many   :guests, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :guests

  validates :invitation_id, :presence => true
end
```

**Guest**

```
class Guest < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name, :email, :phone, :message, :attending_wedding, :attending_bbq, :meal_id

  belongs_to :rsvp
  belongs_to :meal

  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :name,    :presence => true
  validates :email,   :allow_blank => true, :format => { :with => email_regex }
  validates :attending_wedding, :inclusion => {:in => [true, false]}
  validates :attending_bbq, :inclusion => {:in => [true, false]}
  validates :rsvp_id, :presence => true
  validates :meal_id, :presence => true
end
```

My logic is that I will seed the database with invitations, and when guests log into the site, they will be presented with an RSVP form, with a section for each guest (using form_for in the view).

The new and create action in my rsvps_controller are:

```
def new
    @title = "Edit RSVP"
    @rsvp = current_invitation.build_rsvp
    current_invitation.guest_count.times { @rsvp.guests.build }
    @meals = Meal.all
  end

  def create
    @rsvp = current_invitation.build_rsvp(params[:rsvp])
    if @rsvp.save
      flash[:success] = "RSVP Updated."
      redirect_to :rsvp
    else
      @title = "Edit RSVP"
      @meals = Meal.all
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

As it stands, this code will not save the RSVP, as it complains that "Guests rsvp can't be blank". I understand that this is (probably) because the rsvp record has not yet been saved to the DB, hence does not yet have an ID. I can get this to work by removing the validation on rsvp_id, but that feels wrong - after all, all Guest records **should** have an association with an RSVP, so I think the validation should stay. On the other hand, without the validation, the record associations are correct if I look at the through the console.

What's the standard (idiomatic rails) way of handling this situation?

Thanks,
Noel

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much hit the nail on the head "because the rsvp record has not yet been saved to the DB". The association is there, the `rsvp_id` is not.

You could create a custom validator though. Something like...

```
class Guest < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  validate :associated_to_rsvp
  ...
private
  def associated_to_rsvp
    self.errors.add(:rsvp, "does not exist.") unless self.rsvp
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Azolo, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the problem. I get the same error as when using `validates :rsvp_id, :presence => true`